# Georeferencing TIFF photo not saving control points to image in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, geotiff-tiff, georeferencing

I have scanned historical air photos and am trying to georeference them in ArcGIS Pro 3.0.

**Current attempted steps:**

1. I bring in the TIFF file and it goes to the points `0,0`
2. I select the TIFF in the TOC
3. click Georeference under the Imagery tab
4. zoom to area of interest
5. then add control points
6. When things are lined up, I then press Save under the Georeference tab.
7. I then select Close Georeference and **this is when the image goes back to the points `0,0`**.

It appears the control points I have created are not saving to the TIFF.

I've even tried refreshing and closing the project, and bringing the TIFF back in, however, I can't seem to figure out why the control points are not saving with the image.

Answer (score 1):

Control points are never saved to the tiff file. You either SAVE AS NEW to create a new raster with its new coordinates or you Export the Control points to a separate text file which if so desired you can load back and apply to another raster.

[image: Ribbon]

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I've now tried the SAVE AS NEW option (with Output format as TIFF), however getting an error that says 'Failed to export the data.' Any ideas about this?

Comment: Without screen shots, information about your input raster, coordinate systems, where you are trying to write the output then the answer is no. You need to edit your question and add that detail. At the moment this is a how long is a piece of string question...